# Elements after css::after pseudoclass are overlaping div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was trying to reshape my div adding some extra shape after div with ::after pseudoclass,
so it looks like this:

CODESANDBOX: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-goldstine-gdueg?file=/index.html

[image]

Why this h2 tag after this div::after is overlaping div, why this isnt below this purple element. How can i achive this:

[image]

I dont want to add margin to h2 tag after this pseudoclass. Ty for all solutions!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you have restricted the div height to `400px` set more height for the parent so you could avoid the problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.dv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #25aaa0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dv::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 405px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  /* background-color: #25aaa0; */
  background-color: blueviolet;
  clip-path: ellipse(65% 50% at 50% 50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
/*400px is the height of the div .dv and 85px is the height of the pseudo element's height 500px - cut off height on top:405px */
.container {height: calc(400px + 85px);}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="dv">
        <h2>Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Test</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ty for solution. But why height of dv::after isnt automaticly added to parent container height, i mean dv::after is chield of container ?

Comment: But you have written for the dv so it is basically the children of dv + dv has position: relative too absolute element will respect its parent not the grandparent. In order to do so remove position:relative from `.dv` and set `position:inherit` and set `position: relative` to container

Comment: Note: HTML does not use and does not need or require a closing slash on any tag and never has in any HTML specification.